# Getting date from a given string in Android

Tags: android, datetime, date

Hello I am new to Android. Can anybody help me get date like `2012-07-15` from `15 July`. I know that is done by using `DateFormater` but I don't know how it's working? Please help me to find this.

Comment: [Let me do it For you?](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ii thing use this by using subString() method

```
   String TimeZOne = "2012-07-08" 
    String Year = TimeZOne.substring(0,4); 
    String month = TimeZOne.substring(4,7); 
    String date = TimeZOne.substring(8,10);

    int Month_1 = Integer.parseInt(month);
    String month_String = find_Month(date_1);//call method

    String date_Fromate = date+" "+month_String ;
```

//declare method

```
public String Date_String(int i){

switch (i) 
                {
                    case (i==1): 
                    {
                        month = "JAN";
                        break;
                    }
                    case (i==2): 
                    {
                        month = "FEB";
                        break;
                    }
                    case (i==3): 
                    {
                        month = "MAR";
                        break;
                    }
                    case (i==4): 
                    {
                        month = "APR";
                        break;
                    }
                    case (i==5): 
                    {
                        month = "MAY";
                        break;
                    }
                    case (i==6): 
                    {
                        month = "JUN";
                        break;
                    }
                    case (i==7): 
                    {
                        month = "JUL";
                        break;
                    }
                    case (i==8): 
                    {
                        month = "AUG";
                        break;
                    }
                    case (i==9): 
                    {
                        month = "SEP";
                        break;
                    }
                    case (i==10): 
                    {
                        month = "OCT";
                        break;
                    }
                    case (i==11): 
                    {
                        month = "NOV";
                        break;
                    }
                    case (i==12): 
                    {
                        month = "DEC";
                        break;
                    }
                }
         return month;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
public static String convertStringToDate(String startDate) throws ParseException
    {
        String myFormatString = "dd-MMM-yyyy"; // Your startDate Format
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormatString);
        Date startingDate = df.parse(startDate);

        DateFormat dateFormat= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");  // Date format what you want
        return dateFormat.format(startingDate);
    }
```

Comment: just what i was about to write :)m also for more info on how to format dates, look here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html  it is pretty well explained

Comment: Hello @chirag thank you for reply. From your example i get 1970-15-05. means year give 1970 but its 2012. wt i do in that?

Comment: Your answer before edited is work for me but only problem in year which give 1970 not 2012.

Comment: in myFormatString date you need to parse 15 July date format.

Comment: Yes dude. so i write "dd MMM" in myFormatString. everything is right only year have 1970 value.

Comment: its because you are not providing year format in that passing date . so it takes default year 1970

Comment: String date1 = "15 July 2012"; and check

Answer (score 0):

try this code sample

```
    String date1 = "15 July 2012";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
    Date testDate = null;
    try {
        testDate = sdf.parse(date1);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(testDate);

    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    date1 = sdf.format(testDate); 
    System.out.println(date1);
```